# How to play Base64 encoded audio in android?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

What I have tried till now :-

- Have a Base64 encoded String of an audio file.

Now here I am trying to play like this.

```
public void PlayAudio(String base64EncodedString){
        try
        {
            String url = "data:audio/mp3;base64,"+base64EncodedString;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
            /*mediaPlayer.prepare();*/
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void playMp3(byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) {
        try {
            // create temp file that will hold byte array
            File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("kurchina", "mp3", getCacheDir());
            tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
            fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
            fos.close();

            // resetting mediaplayer instance to evade problems
            mediaPlayer.reset();

            // In case you run into issues with threading consider new instance like:
            // MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            // Tried passing path directly, but kept getting
            // "Prepare failed.: status=0x1"
            // so using file descriptor instead
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

            //mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            String s = ex.toString();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But audio is not playing.

May any one assist me over this.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to decode the Base64 encoded String before you play it. Please check the decoding procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448865/base64-encode-audio-file-and-send-as-a-string-then-decode-the-string)

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Let me check it once. WIll get back to you.

Comment: Not working... Can be there any sort of encoding issue, as I am encoding an audio file over web?

Comment: Well it is possible! All you can do is to check that also and search for a standard encoding method.

Comment: Also compare the encoded string from the web with what you are actually receiving at the android end.